# How can I understand Luttinger's theory of thermal transport coefficients?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, thermoelectricity

I am trying to understand Luttinger's research paper

> [Theory of Thermal Transport Coefficients, J. M. Luttinger Phys. Rev.
> 135, A1505 – Published 14 September 1964](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.135.A1505)

While I am able to understand the main concept of his work, I am unable to reproduce his mathematical steps.

I wonder if there is any book or lecture notes/videos in which this research paper or in general thermal transport coefficients are discussed with mathematical steps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a book, but an extended  discussion of the idea can be found in the paper

N. R. Cooper, B. I. Halperin, I. M. Ruzin, *Thermoelectric response of an interacting two-dimensional electron gas in a quantizing magnetic field*, Phys Rev B 55 2344-2359 (1997)

Comment: wow. thank you very much, sir. I think I will be able to clear all my confusion with the help of this article.